# Python/Pandas equivalent to Excel SUMIFS function with two datasets involved

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, sumifs

I have a SUMIFS function involving two excel sheets for calculations
=SUMIFS('Sheet_1'!$D:$D, 'Sheet_2'!$A:$A,">"&'Some_Value', 'Sheet_2'!$B:$B,"<="&'Some_Value_2')

I am able to implement the SUMIFS function in pandas with the use of df.query() method where all the fields are from same excel sheet. df.query([criterias])['column_to_be_summed_up'].sum()
How to figure out the SUMIFS with multiple criteria from multiple sheets?

Not able to figure out the syntax or logic for this

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected ouput? E.g. small 2 datasets with 4 columns and 3 rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to read different sheets with different df names first as following:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
```

And then, you have to join these to different Dataframes.
I've given inner method as an example but for your case outer join can be usefull

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='{column_name'))
```

And after this process you can query your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! creating a temp df and then applying the df.query() function on it